# VS 2019 - SSAS Tabular model explorer missing or greyed out

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, ssas, ssas-tabular

I searched many times, but there was no answer from MSFT or any other communities for this issue.

I have the Community edition 2019. Tabular model explorer is greyed out in the View->Toolbar->Other windows. I have no luck with VS 2017 EE as well, the same problem there too.

I could able to use the Import Datasource button on the Model menu and pull the source tables for building, however, Tabular model explorer and the data source folders are missing or not being able to use from a project perspective. Since the tabular model explorer is missing, I couldn't able to use the data transform window for each table and thus literally making a stop on development.

This is really annoying.

Here is VS 2019 system info

---

Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019
Version 16.5.3
VisualStudio.16.Release/16.5.3+30002.166
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.7.03062

Installed Version: Community

SQL Server Analysis Services   15.0.19049.0
Microsoft SQL Server Analysis Services Designer 
Version 15.0.19049.0

SQL Server Data Tools   16.0.62003.05170
Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools

SQL Server Integration Services   15.0.2000.93
Microsoft SQL Server Integration Services Designer
Version 15.0.2000.93

SQL Server Reporting Services   15.0.19049.0
Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services Designers 
Version 15.0.19049.0

---

[Update 04/10/2020- Attached screenshot of the greyed out window menu]
[SSAS Tabular Explorer Window greyed out][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2B15d.png)

Comment: So have you opened the .bim file in your SSAS Tabular project so that the model editor is open? And the Tabular Model Explorer pane is still grayed out? Can you provide a screenshot?

Comment: @GregGalloway: I have attached the screenshot. Please check and help. TIA

Answer (score 5):

In your screenshot, Model.bim does not appear to be open. You have to open it for Tabular Model Explorer to show up. Double click **Model.bim** in **Solution Explorer**.

Other issues that I don't believe apply to you, but may to others:

1. The Compatibility Level of the model must be at least 1400. Check by selecting Model.bim in Solution Explorer and then look in the Properties Window.
2. You also must have the Analysis Services extension installed. Search on "SSDT" for current installation steps.

Answer (score 2):

If you left click on the Model.bim File in solution explorer and look at the properties window you should see Compatibility Level is 1103 or less. You will need to upgrade to a newer compatibility level to use Tabular Model Explorer. What version is your SSAS Server? You can upgrade to that level or lower.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using compatibility level 1400, in which you have to click on the Design button instead - see this [Microsoft reply](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/c360002a-e838-4206-b917-847d016feb41/table-preview-mode-unavailable-in-ssas-tabular-models?forum=sqlanalysisservices).

Answer (score -1):

You need to install the Analysis services tabular projects extension from the Marketplace. Post that you should be able to see the tabular model explorer

Answer (score -1):

I have 1400 compatibility level and still the tabular explorer didn't show up, it was greyed, it's some kind of bug, you can solve it by simply double clicking again on the model and opening it.