# Tabular Model Explorer not showing in VS 2019

Tags: visual-studio-2019, ssas

**Note**

**I have already checked this question [VS 2019 - SSAS Tabular model explorer missing or greyed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61104552/vs-2019-ssas-tabular-model-explorer-missing-or-greyed-out) and according the answers, I had to open Model.bim file but still no tabular explorer showing**

**What is installed my side?**

**Visual studio 2019**

[image]

**SQL Server 2014**

[image]

**Compatibility page while creating the new tabular project**

[image]

**Missing Tab**

[image]
Am I missing anything? Please let me know if you need more info.

Answer (score 0):

Tabular Model Explorer isn’t available for compatibility levels under 1200.

Comment: in that case should I install MS SQL Server 2016?

Comment: @Pankaj if you can upgrade the server you are deploying to then yes, SQL 2016 or higher.

Comment: Should I uninstall version 2014 and install 2016, will it work that way?

Comment: @Pankaj you can have multiple instances of different versions if you want. Or you can do an in place upgrade.